# Absolute positioning causing horizontal scroll

Tags: css, css-position

I have a cloud which moves from just inside the screen to off the screen with a CSS3 animation. When the cloud is off the screen, the screen scrolls horizontally which is not ideal. I can hide the scrollbar with CSS, but I'd like to prevent the scroll.

```
#c-2 {
background:url(clouds.png) no-repeat;
width:161px;
height:94px;
position:absolute;
top:40%;
right:0%;
animation:CloudB 20s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
-moz-animation:CloudB 20s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation:CloudB 20s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
-o-animation:CloudB 20s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes CloudB {
    0%   { right:0%; top:40%; }
    100% { right:-10%; top:40%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes CloudB {
    0%   { right:0%; top:40%; }
    100% { right:-10%; top:40%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes CloudB {
    0%   { right:0%; top:40%; }
    100% { right:-10%; top:40%; }
}

@-o-keyframes CloudB {
    0%   { right:0%; top:40%; }
    100% { right:-10%; top:40%; }
}
```

http://energycenter.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/m3af2/

```
body {
    background-color: #99CCE8;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you could put overflow:hidden without specifying axis and will work as well yeah?

Comment: @SantiagoRebella nope, if you put it without the axis and your page will be taller than the window - it will be cut off

Comment: @ZoltanToth This doesn't work. I can hide the scrollbar by adding overflow-x:hidden to the html element, but that doesn't stop the page from scrolling horizontally, it just hides the scrollbar.

Comment: I've added a link to the site, in case the problem is being caused by other issues that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Ahhh, I use Chrome. It doesn't work in Chrome, I just checked in latest version FF, works fine. Any idea why it won't work in webkit?

Comment: put the `overflow: hidden` on the `body`, not `html`

Comment: @ZoltanToth Still same problem. It's worse again in Safari, the page actually scrolls automatically.

Comment: add `position: relative` to body (see updated answer) - that will make consistent the clouds in all browsers. After adjust their position